# jQuery UI sortable's placeholder pushes elements under it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder

I'm working on a concept for a image manager in a webshop system. Part of the requirements is that on product level you can upload images for that product and by dragging (sorting) the images you can choose the order in wich the images is being displayed on the product page.

My problem is that i use a placeholder for the element is being dragged, and that element is pushing to the elements on the next line/row of images.

**Sortable code:**

```
$('.product-image-manager').sortable({
    handle: '.fa-arrows',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: '> .image-container',
    placeholder: 'image-placeholder',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
        ui.placeholder.html('<div class="inner-placeholder"></div>');
    }
});
```

**[Full example](http://codepen.io/legarth/pen/yayzNq)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```
.product-image-manager > .image-container {
    padding: 8px;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

To this:

```
.product-image-manager > .image-container {
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: You my dear sir is a life saver! (You will get the bounty in 5 hours)